# When does firebaseAuth.getAuth() become non-null in relation to firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

The correct way to identify when a user is authenticated from a cold start when using the firebase auth package is to use the [`onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onauthstatechanged) function, like so:

```js
firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged(firebase.getAuth(), (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

firebase also provides [`getAuth`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#getauth) as a way to get the current auth state.

It seems that `getAuth` lags behind `onAuthStateChanged`; `getAuth().currentUser` will return null before `onAuthStateChanged`, and at some point after `onAuthStateChanged` will return the currentUser. My question is: at what point exactly does it become safe to use `getAuth().currentUser` (EDIT: 'safe' meaning 'getAuth will reflect the state represented in onAuthStateChanged')?

Unfortunately the existing [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) does not make this clear

ETA: filed a bug report here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6752

Comment: You should really use the auth state observer callback for everything.  It gives you an up-to-the-moment view of the current user, since you never know when they might choose to be signed in or signed out, or be forced to signed out. currentUser only gives you a moment-in-time view of the user at the time you use it (again, which can change at any time, outside of your control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: At what point exactly does it becomes safe to use
> getAuth().currentUser?

There isn't any real answer to your question, in particular because you don't define what do you mean by "it becomes safe".

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) you refer to in your question, the auth object "can be in an intermediate state such as initialization". In this case `getAuth().currentUser` will be null because the auth object has not finished initializing. The duration of the initialization of the auth object in your specific case/environment cannot be known upfront (it's outside of your control) and it's up to you to deal with this specific behaviour.

So to keep track of the user's sign-in status, either you use an observer , i.e. you use `onAuthStateChanged()` or you call `getAuth().currentUser` but you need to handle the specific case when it is null.

As written in the documentation, the recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object, i.e. by using `onAuthStateChanged()`.

Comment: added an explanation of what I mean by 'safe'.

I think what you're saying is that there is no way to use getAuth().currentUser in a way that accurately reflects onAuthStateChanged? That seems...really weird to me, so I apologize if I'm misunderstanding. 

"In this case getAuth().currentUser will be null because the auth object has not finished initializing"

Are you saying there is no way to know when the auth object in getAuth() has finished initializing?

Comment: "Are you saying there is no way to know when the auth object in getAuth() has finished initializing?" => The only direct way is to use `onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {...}`: if `user` is not null, the auth object has finished initializing. You could check the value of `getAuth().currentUser`every x seconds but this is not a very efficient approach.

Comment: interesting. So to follow up, lets say I called firebase.getAuth() after I was sure onAuthStateChanged fired and I knew that a user was present. If I'm understanding you right, getAuth is still potentially undetermined?

This seems much closer to a bug than an implementation detail

Comment: I was probably not clear in my last comment. When the observer is triggered with a non null user, getAuth().currentUser Is non null.

Comment: Hey @theahura, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: I ended up filing a bug here (including repro code): https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6752

I don't think the behavior as described really makes sense. I think your answer is an accurate description of the current state of things, so I can approve it (but maybe it is worth clarifying that the answer isn't feasible regardless of the definition of 'safe')

Comment: Thanks for your message. I personally don't think there is a bug here. Firebase methods are **asynchronous** and the recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object by using `onAuthStateChanged()`. If you don't want to use the observer nothing prevents you to use `getAuth().currentUser`but you have to know that it may be null (if the user is not signed in **OR** if the Auth object is currently in a intermediate state such as initialization) and it's up to you to deal with this case.

Comment: With all respect, even if this is working as intended, it is terrible design to the point where it might as well be a bug. Whether or not the methods are async or not is separate from the issue that the onAuthStateChange and the getAuth do not reflect each other at all

Comment: With all my respect as well (after all we are having a discussion on a feature that we are not responsible for :-)) I think that onAuthStateChange and the getAuth do reflect each other. If onAuthStateChange returns that user is null, getAuth will do so. And vice versa. The "problem" is more that your question is "at what point exactly does getAuth().currentUser is not null." The answer is "call it and check OR use onAuthStateChange".

Comment: "If onAuthStateChange returns that user is null, getAuth will do so."

This is not true, and the bug I submitted includes code that shows this is not true.

Comment: I just looked at your github issue and it seems there is an error in your code, see the update by sam-gc